# Linker can't find functions even if they are in a static lib

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld

I have a static library that compiles, and looks (simplified) like this :

math_util.h :

```
void foo(...);
```

math_util.cpp :

```
void foo(...) { ... }
```

A.cpp :

```
#include "math_util.h"
class A 
{
    bar() {
        foo(...);
    }
}
```

The static lib compiles fine.
However, when I want to use `A` in a real app, I get :

```
undefined reference to `foo(...)'
```

But when I check my static lib with nm :

```
math_util.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
000000000000010a T _ZN8fooEPA2_dPdj
```

This is not a prototype problem, because if I copy the code of `foo` into A.cpp it works fine.

So, I don't get it, why can't G++ find the symbol, even if it is obviously present in the static lib ?
I don't have this problem for any other function.

Note: in case of, I am running Linux, with QtCreator and I use qmake for both projects (but the static lib is pure STL C++, Qt is not involved).

Edit : to see the real, involved files :

https://github.com/jcelerier/spectral-subtraction/blob/master/libnoisered/math_util.h

https://github.com/jcelerier/spectral-subtraction/blob/master/libnoisered/math_util.cpp

A.cpp :

https://github.com/jcelerier/spectral-subtraction/blob/master/libnoisered/estimation/simple_estimation.cpp

Project file :

https://github.com/jcelerier/spectral-subtraction/blob/master/libnoisered/libnoisered.pro

Comment: Show much more of your source code, and give the actual compilation procedure (or `Makefile`).

Comment: I use qmake, which in turns generate makefiles.
You just have to specify `SOURCES = (cpp files)` and `HEADERS = (header files)` in a project.pro file and it takes care of it, a bit like CMake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your signature in the `.h` file;

```
void compute_power(fftw_complex *in, double *powoutput, int size);
```

is not compatible with the signature in the `.cpp` file;

```
void compute_power(fftw_complex *in, double *powoutput, unsigned int size)
```

They are name mangled to different symbols for linking.

Change them to be the same, and things should link.

Comment: Argh, I had double checked it maybe twenty times... Vicious little unsigned. Thanks!